# CSRF token mismatch Laravel ajax delete data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-6

I want to delete data from a database with an `ajax` call but it's showing an error.

> CSRF token mismatch

In header:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In blade:

```
<button class="deletePhoto" data-id="{{ $photo->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">Delete</button>
```

AJAX call:

```
$('.deletePhoto').click(function () {

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var el = this;

    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers:{
           'X_CSRF_TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/photo/delete/'+id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{
            'id': id,
        },
        success: function () {
            $(el).closest(".photo-details").remove();
            console.log('DELETED');
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
})
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $photo = Photo::find($id);
    $photo->delete();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I usually do : **[AJAX CALL]**

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/photo/delete/'+id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data:{
        'id': id,
        '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
    },
    success: function () {
        el.closest(".photo-details").remove();
        console.log('DELETED');
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
})
```